# Regex use to split a string with an OPTIONAL SEPARATOR (char)

Tags: python, string

I have a string that looks like this: new_tt_j1213.

I need to split it into 'new', 'tt', 'j1213'.

string rules:

1. The first three characters are always letters
2. after the first '_' (if it is present) there are 2 letters only
3. after the second '_' (if it is present) there are EITHER t1524 OR t014 formats (the first symbol is always a letter and there can be 3 or 4 digits)
4. all letters are lower case
5. '_' can be missing due to corruption

It is very easy with the split() method BUT because data is corrupted sometimes the first underscore is missing: 'newtt_j1213'

Since I am very new to Regex, can you help me to adjust my code below so the split works as described even without the first '_'. (or even without the 2nd underscore)?

```
 p1 =''
 p2 =''
 p3 =''

str_t = 'newtt_j123'
str_t1 = 'new_tt_j1213'
str_t2 = 'newttj1213'
str3 = 'new_ttj1213'

#   Test for data Corruption
 tr_lst = re.split('_', str_t)   
 if len(tr_lst) <3: print('DATA CORRUPTION - ',tr_lst)     
    
 p1, p2, p3 = re.split('_', str_t) # THIS LINE NEEDS ADJUSTMENT (REGEX?)
 print(p1, p2, p3, str_t)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What are the patterns in the string? i.e. is the first letter 'n' literally always the letter n or is it always multiple ascii characters of length 1?

Comment: @alex - the first char is always a letter. in fact, there are no digits except for the last 4 (eg f1524) OR the last 3 (eg f014) characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you can do it without regex.

First remove all `_` if present with `s.replace('_', '')`
Next use bracket to extract like this :

```
s = "newtt_j1213"
s = s.replace('_', '')
ss = [ s[0:3], s[3:5], s[5:] ]
print(ss)
```

Output:
`['new', 'tt', 'j1213']`

Comment: works! and so simple!

Comment: @Toby is quite frustrating that I asked you so many times if there was a fixed length pattern, and that you gave examples with different lengths to see that *in fine*, everything is fixed length... Anyway, glad you got what you need but you would have had it much sooner if you had asked a clear question from the beginning...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your strings are in the form "ABB_CCCCC" or "A_BB_CCCCC" and you want to extract A/BB/CCCCC.

You could use:

```
import re
re.findall('(.)_?([^_]+)_(.+)', your_string)[0]
```

*NB1. If you always have 1 character, 2 characters, 5 characters, use: `'(.)_?(..)_(.{5})'`*

*NB2. this assumes here that the strings are valid for one or the other formula, else you will have no match and an IndexError*

example:

```
s1 = 'n_tt_j1213'
re.findall('(.)_?([^_]+)_(.+)', your_string)[0]
```

```
s2 = 'ntt_j1213'
re.findall('(.)_?([^_]+)_(.+)', your_string)[0]
```

output for both:

```
('n', 'tt', 'j1213')
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work as expected. I updated the strings in the question (eg t2 = 'new_sn_f1524'). I am receiving n ew sn_f1524 (4 elements instead of 3) from 'new_sn_f1524'. I need 'new', 'sn', 'f1524'

Comment: how would you differenciate 'new_sn_f1524' and 'ne_wsn_f1524'? Is any of the fields fixed width? Are there fixed characters? If not, this is an impossible task

Comment: 'ne_wsn_f1524' is impossible.  it can only be: new_sn_f1524 OR newsn_f1524 OR new_snf1524 OR newsnf1524.  Nothing else is possible.

Comment: Yes, but **how** do you know? ;)

Comment: These cases are the only ones that I need to cover. The rest will go to another team. Also, there can be 4 OR 3 digits at the end. Both cases are legit (not corruption) My original split() covered them. At the minimum, please cover only the cases: new_tt_m1524, newtt_f1524, new_tt_f014, and newtt_m014.

Comment: What I mean, is **how** do you tell the program what is valid and what isn't, from it's perspective, there is no way to know where to split if nothing is fixed width and letters only. For instance if I tell you "goodmorning" and you don't speak english, there is no way that you can know where to split. If I say "GoodMorning" and explain you need to split on Capital letters, you can achieve the task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237537/discussion-between-toly-and-mozway).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('^([a-z]{3}).*([a-z]{2}).*([a-z]{1}\d{3})$')
matches = re.search(regex, 'newtt_j123')
print(matches.groups())
```

OUT:
`('new', 'tt', 'j123')`

The regex works like this:
`^([a-z]{3})` anchors the match to the start of the string and then matches 3 lowercase letters and stores this in the first capture group. The [a-z] is a character class which means any lowercase letters, the 3 in curly brackets mean it has to be of length 3. It's in a capture group because it's in normal brackets (i.e. () ).

Then greedily match anything with .* up to the next capture group and`([a-z]{2})` any two lowercase letters.

Then again greedily match anything up to to the last capture group with `([a-z]{1}\d{3})`. This matches one lowercase letter next to three numbers, which is denoted by `\d`.

Then when you print out `matches.groups()` you will get the matches in that order, i.e. the first one will be the three letters, the next one will be the next two letters, and the last one will be the letter followed by three numbers.

I also used `^` and `$` to anchor the matches to the start and end of the string.

Comment: it threw an error for new_sn-f1524 but worked on new_sn-f014. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' for print statement

Comment: Hey, that's expcted since f1524 has 4 digits after f rather than just 3. If you're going to vary it between 3 or 4 digits at the end you could change it to {3,4} like this:

'^([a-z]{3}).*([a-z]{2}).*([a-z]{1}\d{3,4})$'